# VertexLabels with Graph Properties

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have a graph like this

```
Graph[
  {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, Labeled[3 <-> 1, "hello"]}, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name",StatusArea]
]
```

Now I want to add more properties to all the nodes.

For instance, I want to replace name of node 1 by number 3700, node 2 by 3701, node3 by 3703 and those should be displayed only in the status area.

Along with replacing the node names, I also want some more properties associated with nodes. For instance, I'd like `3700, "h1"` to be displayed in the status area when I place my mouse pointer at node 1; at node 2, it should display `3700, "h2"` etc. (not exactly those but some other display stuff).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

Set a graph with properties:

```
g = Graph[{Property[1, "Custom" -> {3700, "h1"}], 
    Property[2, "Custom" -> {3700, "h2"}], 
    Property[3, "Custom" -> {3700, "h2"}]}, {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 
    3 <-> 1}];
```

Define labels:

```
labels = # -> Placed[ToString[PropertyValue[{g, #}, "Custom"], InputForm], 
      StatusArea] & /@ VertexList[g];
```

Draw graph:

```
SetProperty[g, VertexLabels -> labels]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @halmir, thanks for the answer. But I have a graph which has a very large number of nodes. So I cannot really write the property for every vertex. Is there any way I can generalize the code for all of them?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can just map properties over you vertices. What do you have?