# Label graphs based on custom properties

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is it possible to make (`Weighted`)`AdjacencyMatrix` from a graph whose elements have custom properties?

Consider this graph:

```
g = Graph[{
      Property[DirectedEdge[0, 1], {"WaterFlow" -> x, "PipeWidth" -> 10.0}],
      Property[DirectedEdge[1, 2], {"WaterFlow" -> x + y, "PipeWidth" -> 8.5}],
      Property[DirectedEdge[2, 1], {"WaterFlow" -> y, "PipeWidth" -> 8.5}],
      Property[DirectedEdge[2, 3], {"WaterFlow" -> x, "PipeWidth" -> 10.0}]
    }]
```

[image]

How do I set the option `EdgeLabels` for `Graph` so that all the edges are labeled according to a given custom property, say `"WaterFlow"`, or `"PipeWidth"`?

Comment: I know this is a hack, but the support for custom graph properties could be better.  If you define `edges` to be your list, then `Graph[edges /. 
  Rule["WaterFlow", x_] :> 
   Sequence[Rule["WaterFlow", x], Rule[EdgeLabels, x]]]` works

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104923/9490) is related, if not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g2 = SetProperty[g, 
       {VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", 
        EdgeWeight -> (# -> PropertyValue[{g, #}, "WaterFlow"] & /@ EdgeList[g]),
        EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g2] // Normal
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

More generally, define a function to identify the `EdgeWeight`s with a property:

```
ClearAll[f]
f = With[{g = #, prop = #2}, 
    SetProperty[g, {VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", 
      EdgeWeight -> (# -> PropertyValue[{g, #}, prop] & /@ EdgeList[g]),
      EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"}]] &;

f[g, "WaterFlow"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[g, "PipeWidth"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[f[g, "PipeWidth"]] // Normal
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

As the coming function of `IGEdgeMap` and `IGEdgeProp` in prerelease version [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), the life become easier

```
IGEdgeMap[# &, EdgeLabels -> IGEdgeProp[#], g] & /@ {"WaterFlow", "PipeWidth"}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]